# Make domain work for website and admin-panel

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a domain like `example.com` which is working fine with below `.htaccess` code. The build for website is in this path: `vdsta_app/website`
and it is working fine

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!vdsta_app/website/).*)$ /vdsta_app/website/$1 [L,NC]
```

Now I want my admin panel to work on `example.com/admin-panel`

admin-panel build is in this path: `vdsta_app/admin-panel/`

I tried some code but not working.
Please give some suggestions.

Comment: Do you have multiple domains / hostnames on your site?

Comment: As per [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283057/mod-rewrite-questions-getting-migrated-to-sf) and [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283033/are-htaccess-questions-ever-on-topic-at-so) this question is not at all off-topic for SO so close vote is wrong. This has been discussed again and again and it has been settled already that most of the rewrite rules are created and maintained by developers of the web applications/frameworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your existing rule rewrites everything that does not already start with `vdsta_app/website/` to `vdsta_app/website/<whatever>`, so if you need a more specific rewrite then it must go *before* your existing rule.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin-panel(?:/(.*))?$ /vdsta_app/admin-panel/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!vdsta_app/(website|admin-panel)/).*)$ /vdsta_app/website/$1 [L,NC]
```

Also adding the `admin-panel` to the negative lookahead in the 2nd rule.

If you don't have multiple domains / hostnames then you can remove the *condition* that checks the `Host` header. Or move this into its own *exception* rule.

Comment: @TristateTechnology How did you get on with this?